# How can I display an exception during rendering?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am getting the following exception in my code:

```
Error 12:21:42 [] LouisHowe.web.Shared.MainLayout - Error: 781a8157-884a-4926-a9f5-3497950411a5 ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'stringToEscape')
   at System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String paramName)
   at System.ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(Object argument, String paramName)
   at System.UriHelper.EscapeString(String stringToEscape, Boolean checkExistingEscaped, SearchValues`1 noEscape)
   at CommonUtilities.Utilities.UriUtils.<>c.<CreateUrl>b__0_0(ValueTuple`2 p) in C:\Git\LouisHowe\CommonUtilities\Utilities\UriUtils.cs:line 23
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.String.Join(String separator, IEnumerable`1 values)
   at CommonUtilities.Utilities.UriUtils.CreateUrl(String path, ValueTuple`2[] parameters) in C:\Git\LouisHowe\CommonUtilities\Utilities\UriUtils.cs:line 20
   at LouisHowe.web.Pages.EventJob.EventGridEdit.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.<BuildRenderTree>b__10(RenderTreeBuilder __builder3) in C:\Git\LouisHowe\LouisHowe.web\Pages\EventJob\EventGridEdit.razor:line 42
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder.AddContent(Int32 sequence, RenderFragment fragment)
   at DevExpress.Blazor.Internal.GridCommandCell.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)
```

I have an `<ErrorBoundary>` in my MainLayout.razor. The key part is:

```
<ErrorContent Context="error">
    @{
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var useFallback = true;
        if (error.Data.Contains("Category"))
        {
            var data = error.Data["Category"];
            if (data is Type category)
            {
                var logger = LoggerFactory.CreateLogger(category);
                logger.LogError(error, "Error: {guid}", guid);
                useFallback = false;
            }
        }
        if (useFallback)
        {
            Logger.LogError(error, "Error: {guid}", guid);
        }
    }

    <h1>Unexpected Error (sorry)</h1>

    <p>
        The program has encountered an unexpected error (yes there are expected errors). This error has been
        logged and we will look at it.
    </p>

    <p>We suggest you <a href="/identity/account/LogOut">logout</a> and then log back in if you wish to try again.</p>

    <p>If you want to contact us, please include the following error id: @guid when you do.</p>

</ErrorContent>
```

Usually it logs the above **and** displays the content. But sometimes the page is blank. I get the log output (I think, never sure if that particular case logged).

Any reason why this would sometimes be blank?

Comment: What is the `Logger` in the `useFallback` section?

Comment: It is in the code behind `[Inject] 
private ILogger<MainLayout> Logger { get; set; } = default!;`